# Command with options in GNU env shebang line throws error

Tags: shell, gnu, bsd, shebang

It turns out that a [tool for evaluating json](https://github.com/fatso83/pick_json) that has been humming along nicely on my Mac wasn't as cross platform as I thought. Once I installed it on Ubuntu I got this error:

```
npm install -g pick_json
echo '{ "foo" : {  "bar" : 2 } }' | pick_json -e foo.bar
/usr/bin/env: ‘node --harmony’: No such file or directory
```

It turns out that GNU `env` thinks the command with the argument [in the shebang line](https://github.com/fatso83/pick_json/blob/master/pick_json.js#L1) should be evaluated as one string. This does not happen on BSD. Manually evaluating the same command on the command line seems to be fine - the error only happens when it is written in the file.

```
$ /usr/bin/env node --harmony
>
```

I have tried various to no avail, so the question remains:

**How can I pass options to the command in the shebang line that will work with GNU's `env` command?**

Answer (score 1):

> The #! syntax is generally called the Berkeley #! hack.  It was a
>   wonderful improvement over not having it at all.  But is still
>   considered a hack because it has many limitations.  One is that only
>   one argument is allowed.  Some operating systems have a limit of not
>   more than 32 characters for the line allowed.